# Force a header to print onto each page of a print job in windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, printing, postscript

Is there a way through the printer settings, in Windows, such that each print job would have a header printed on each page?

Comment: It would help to know the purpose, the program(s) you print from and the printer.  if it is just a single header used on everything, most people would just print a whole stack, then use that (second pass) later for thier letterhead.  Some printer driver softwares have "watermark" capability which can vary so much that it could be used for other things. Many of the windows own printer dialogs have that option, the Key sometimes is to go to Print Preview first, not just print. .

Comment: PG - thanks for your comment. It would be like the postscript in a .sep file but for each page and to be printed with minimal fuss (i.e. happens when you press print). In Win7, .sep files can get variables like windows user, time etc. I'd like these to be printed on on the top (or bottom) line of each page, not just the .sep.

Comment: then add all that, and more info still to the question by editing

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the driver. Some drivers provide feature named "Watermarking". 
It is possible to extend the windows driver to bring this feature but it requires some coding. If Your driver uses PPD or SPD it is possible to define the header in these files and make the driver to embed the PostScript code into every page.